# Trying to Create Buttons from a list with Kivy

Tags: python, user-interface, button, interface, kivy

I am creating a program for my Electronic health records (EHR) where the user, after logging in can create multiple doctors under the same account.

I want to create a screen 'SignIn_MD' where the there is one button for every doctor under the user's list.

assume that kivyfxns work correctly.

I wish to show in the sample dictionary that there would be 2 buttons ('a' and 'b')

I think kivy is not showing the updated DoctorsList layout.  I tried hardcoding a list and it works.. but if I dynamically update with a function, it does not show the buttons

```
`users= {'doctors': ['name':'a', 'name':'b']}`
```

GUI.py

```
`class UserSignIn(Screen):
    username_input = StringProperty('username')
    password_input = StringProperty('password')
    user_error = StringProperty('')
    pass_error = StringProperty('')
    doctor_list = None

    def update_user(self, txt_input):
         self.username_input = txt_input.text
         print(self.username_input)
     def update_pw(self, txt_input):
         self.password_input = txt_input.text
         print(self.password_input)
     def submit(self):
         print('submitted')
         print(self.username_input)
         print(self.password_input)
         check = kivy_fxns.kivy_signin(self.username_input,self.password_input)
         if check == True:
             self.doctor_list = DoctorList()
             self.doctor_list.create_doctor_buttons()
             App.get_running_app().root.current ='SignIn_MD'
         else:
             self.user_error = 'invalid username and password'

class DoctorList(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, \*args, \*\*kwargs):
    super().__init__(\*\*kwargs)
    self.cols = 1

    def create_doctor_buttons(self):
        doctors = kivy_fxns.get_doctors()
        for doctor in doctors:
            btn = Button(text= doctor.get('lastname'), on_release= lambda instance, doctor : self.on_button_click(instance,doctor))
            self.add_widget(btn)`
```

GUI.kv

```
`<SignIn_MD>:
    name: 'SignIn_MD'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'Sign In'
        Label:
            text: 'the following are the list of doctors of user'
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            Label:
                size_hint: 0.25,1
            DoctorList: #does not show any button
            Button: # this button is a sample that works fine
                text: 'sample'
            Label:
                size_hint: 0.25,1
        Label:`
```

Comment: You should post a [mcve]. But the likely problem is that the code: `self.doctor_list = DoctorList()` and the `kv` line: `DoctorList:` are both creating instances of `DoctorList`. But those instances are not related,and the one created in the python code is not part of your GUI.

Comment: Thank you! I finally found my way thinking for this one knowing that I need to call the instance inside the SignIn_MD screen..